# How do I run ElasticSearch on OpenShift?

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

Our applications are onboarding to openshift. we want to do a hassle free elasticsearch setup with clusters and accessible for projects within openshift and  services running in bare metal.

Found a broken older version of elasticsearch cartridge. Any expertise on the latest version of Openshift & elastic search would be appreciated

Openshift: 3.5
Elastic search: 5.5.0

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you talking about. Cartridges are OpenShift 2. The latest version is OpenShift 3 and doesn't use cartridges.

Comment: Openshift: 3.5 Elastic search: 5.5.0

Comment: You can use this repo for starting https://github.com/lbischof/openshift3-elk

Comment: I wrote an article about this recently: https://www.gronau-it-cloud-computing.de/should-we-run-elasticsearch-on-openshift/ . I'd say that if you want to enjoy the full power of elasticsearch, consider bare metal. It's not evil in itself. If you just want "some" elastic stack, check out the EFK that openshift uses itself. Though as an elastic stack person, I don't like it - and it doesn't even always work.